# How to get active hotspot ssid and password programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I'm new to android app development,in my app first activity checks weather Hotspot is on or off, if **hotspot** is on then only it will goes to the next activity.

Now I want to display username and password in next activity, I found only display username but not password, any one help me to how to display password also

Comment: this is not possibly, but why do you want to make a app that shows the passwords of your wifi connection?

Comment: will you share the resiurces for show passwords of wifi connection?

Comment: This sounds slightly fishy.